How to prevent a Primefaces knob label from displaying outside the knob circle when scrolling horizontally?
I'm using Primefaces 13. I have a dataTable with a column that displays a number using p:knob. If all the columns don't fit in the viewport and I scroll the dataTable horizontally, the label of the knob component is displayed outside the knob circle. I could see that it style has position absolute. Changing it to relative fixes the problem, but then the label is not displayed in the circle but below it. Is there a way to prevent this?

I solved the problem using a limited set of knob sizes and adding a CSS class for each size.
CSS looks like this:
div.ui-knob input.knob {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    position: relative  !important;
}

div.ui-knob.xs-knob-size-64 input.knob {
    margin-top: -57px !important;
}

div.ui-knob.xs-knob-size-96 input.knob {
    margin-top: -90px !important;
}

div.ui-knob.xs-knob-size-128 input.knob {
    margin-top: -122px !important;
}

div.ui-knob.xs-knob-size-160 input.knob {
    margin-top: -154px !important;
}

div.ui-knob.xs-knob-size-192 input.knob {
    margin-top: -185px !important;
}

div.ui-knob.xs-knob-size-224 input.knob {
    margin-top: -216px !important;
}

div.ui-knob.xs-knob-size-256 input.knob {
    margin-top: -248px !important;
}

The knob components have a class according to its size, por example:
<p:knob
    height="64" width="64" max="100" min="0" step="1"
    styleClass="xs-knob-size-64"
    value="#{currentRow.descuento}"/>
...
<p:knob
    height="256" width="256" max="1000000" min="0" step="10000"
    styleClass="xs-knob-size-256"
    value="#{currentRow.descuento}"/>

One more thing. If the knob is inside a p:column of a p:dataTable it could be cut if the column is not wide enough. In such cases I added min-width to the style of those p:column to make sure the column width is at least equal to the knob width.
I hope that a future version of Primefaces solves the problem for every possible size of the knob.
